# Menu bar breaks to the next line / fluctuates in size depending on zoom level

Tags: html, css, line-breaks

This is my menu bar at 100% on my browser:
[image]

And this is what happens at certain zoom levels and some other browsers:
[image]

Here's a simplified version on fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/heetertc/ARGm8/6/

```
<div id="bar">
    <div id="center-menu">
        <ul id="nav">
            <li><a href="/about/">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="/bacharach-institute/">THE INSTITUTE</a></li>
            <li><a href="/renaissance-pavilion/">RENAISSANCE PAVILION</a></li>
            <li><a href="/day-rehab/">DAY REHAB</a></li>
            <li><a href="/outpatient-services/">OUTPATIENT SERVICES</a></li>
            <li><a href="/therapy-centers/">THERAPY CENTERS</a></li>
            <li><a href="/blog/">NEWS</a></li>
            <li><a href="/contact/">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<style type="text/css">

ol, ul {
    list-style: none outside none;
}
#bar {
    height: 50px;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: 8px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
#bar ul {
    text-align: center;
}
#center-menu{
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 954px;
}
#nav {
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
#nav li {
    border-left: 1px solid #0c4b89;
    display:block; 
    float:left; 
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding-top: 0;
    position:relative;  
    z-index:500;
}
#nav li a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 50px;
    padding-left: 18px;
    padding-right: 18px;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #000000;
}
#nav > li:last-child {
    border-right: 1px solid #0C4B89;
}

</style>
```

I'm sure this is something really easy, but I've been at it for a few days and tried many different things, including many attempts of resizing.

So why does the last element skip down to the next level, but only at different zooms? When I resize it to fit one zoom level, it looks completely different in another. Is there a way to get this to always fill the 954px #bar element no matter the zoom?

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
White-space: nowrap
```

To #nav